# If I heat the air inside my room with the door open, does the air expanding outside produce work? Consider my room as the thermodynamical system

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm not sure if it is considered a free expansion, since there is air outside.

Comment: Short semi-answer: Yes. The air that is inside your room can not exit without moving the air that was just outside of the door out of the way. Air has mass. In order to start any massive thing moving, you have to exert force on it, and you'll do work as a result. The work that the escaping air does causes the outside air to swirl around, and the energy ultimately will be dissiplated as heat. I have no idea of what kind of heinous fluid-dynamics equations might be involved in calculating exactly how much work/heat.

Comment: @SolomonSlow ok, that makes sense. But now I was thinking: pressure should remain constant, doesnt it? If it does, then the integral of (p*dv)  should equal 0, or not? But that would mean work = 0!